# 古い開発形態の改善

Tags: windows, git, jenkins, redmine, kubernetes

現在とある開発チームでWindows系のアプリのメンテ等を担当しているのですが昨今耳にするようなソフト開発形態と比べるとかなり前近代的な状態だと感じております。

恥ずかしながら具体的には以下のような感じです。
　コンパイラ：VS2012
　言語：C++(MFC)、アセンブラ
　ソースレビュー：しない
　バージョン管理ソフト：使わない
　テストコード：書かない
　バグ管理：Excel

開発が完了したソフトはWEBに掲載して顧客にダウンロードしてもらう形をとっています。
なおソフトウェアの主な処理としては精密機器の制御や状態取得などです。
現在の開発形態を改善することがミッションなのですが、とりあえず

- Gitでのソース管理
- コミットする前のチーム内でのソースレビュー
- Redmineによるバグ管理

を段階的に行っていこうと考えております。
ただ私はこれまで他のソフト開発の職場で働いたことがなく「普通はこうする」や「最近はこういう風に開発する」のような勘所がわからないため、この方向で良いのか、更にもっと良い方法があるのか不安です。

以上を踏まえて質問ですが、

1. 何か上記以外で改善できそうなポイントはありますでしょうか？
2. 開発手法関連で色々調べているとDevOpsという言葉を頻繁に耳にしますが、開発完了したソフトは運用チームに運用されるようなものではなくそのままエンドユーザーの環境にインストールされるだけですのでDevOpsやそれに関連したツール（Jenkins, Kubernetes等）は私の開発チームには馴染まないと思っていますが、そういう理解で合ってますでしょうか？

アドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: やろうとしている事は想像できるのですが、まずは現状の問題点やその中でも改善したい点を明確にすべきかと (現状の質問文だと「範囲が広すぎる」または「内容がはっきりしない」印象を受けます)。 / いま回ってる仕組みから別の方法に切り替えたり、新しいことを始めるには色々とコストがかかります(お金や時間、学習)。単に"モダンな仕組みを取り入れる"ことだけが目標になってしまうと失敗しかねません。

Comment: 「テストコード：書かない」の理由は？　本当は「テストコードが書けない」（なぜなら、プログラムの仕様が十分に理解できていないから）ではないのですか？　テストコードを書かない→バグが点在するプログラムになり想定外の挙動を示す→挙動を修正するために場当たり的対処をする→手の施しようのないプログラムになる、、、、と悪循環におちいりデスパレード（死の行進）に至る。。。。　　こういうシナリオは避けたほうが良いと思いませんか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。機能追加や仕様変更で新たな不具合が混入することが何度かあり、開発体制の改革を迫られている次第です。確かに一つづつ現状の問題点を分析した上で方向性を考えてみるべきだと感じました。テストコードに関しては正直そもそも書く文化がないというところが実情です。不具合防止のためにもそのあたりが今後の改善の焦点かもしれません。

Comment: 回答させていただいた内容が主観的なものだったので、私の回答を削除いたしました。開発体制が改善されますよう頑張ってください。お騒がせして申し訳ありません。

Answer (score 7):

漠然とした質問ではありますが、私も感ずることがあるので要所要所を回答します。

> 上記以外で改善できそうなポイント

あなたの組織のものさしは、何でしょうか。
まずはここを何でも良いので定義しましょう。それを改善する手法を考えます。

> ただ私はこれまで他のソフト開発の職場で働いたことがなく「普通はこうする」や「最近はこういう風に開発する」のような勘所がわからないため、この方向で良いのか、更にもっと良い方法があるのか不安です。

不安があるということは、目的が不明確またはそれを達成できる裏付けが足りないということです。いざ説明しようにも説得力が欠けてしまいます。

「普通」や「流行り」で通用するなら、とっくに「普通」で「流行り」の開発スタイルになっているはずです。
ご自身の組織にどう良い事があるのかきちんと説明できないと、難しいと思ってください。

> 開発手法関連で色々調べているとDevOpsという言葉を頻繁に耳にしますが、

DevOpsなどを採用するチームが、なぜそうしているのかを勉強すべきです。合わないだろうとお感じのとおり、全然別の目的だったりするのではないかと思います。

> ソースレビュー：しない
>   バージョン管理ソフト：使わない
>   テストコード：書かない
>   バグ管理：Excel

これで仕事が回ってきた理由を分析しましょう。属人化とか色々なキーワードが出てくると思います。
そのキーワードを改善する必要性があるか（マネージャーが喜んでくれるか）、改善するにはどういう手法があるのか、どう説得するか、1個ずつ組み上げていくのが現実的です。

簡単なところでは、

- 課題管理システムを導入する　（脱Excel、共同作業しやすい！）
- バージョン管理ソフトで変更履歴の管理を任せる　（手作業で変更履歴残すの面倒だよね！間違えるよね！）
- 上記2個で、課題に対する変更を紐付ける

これらだけから始めても良いと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。またみなさんご指摘の通り漠然とた質問で失礼しました。。「これで仕事が回ってきた理由を分析しましょう。」←この一文に意表を突かれました。おぼろげながらみなさんのおかげで方向が見えました。